# Handling if thread could not enter synchronized(this) block

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I am working on a Robotic Analog to digital button listener.

Where There is a synchronized (this) block when the action performed.

```
public void Init() {   
 new Timer(200, taskPerformer).start();
)

ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //not synchronized code

        synchronized (this) {
               //synchronized code
        }  

    }
}
```

Now my question is How can I understand which Thread Failed to enter that block?
Is there any way so that I can handle those threads. Similar to the if-else , can I handle those thread who could not entered.

Edit: simply want to print("Could not Enter The Block"); How can I do that.?

Thanks.

Comment: All theads that call actionPerformed() should eventually run the synchronized code. Are you asking how to tell when a thread is being blocked?

Comment: I am not sure, but if a thread could not enter that , will enter later. Is it true?

Comment: simply want to print("Could not Enter The Block"); How can I do that.?

Comment: If two threads (T1, and T2) call actionPerform() then they both will execute the synchronized block. They just won't execute it at the same time (this is a simplification).

Comment: Would it be enough to let the first thread do the block, and all subsequent threads print "I was too late"?

Comment: One other thing. Typically actionPerformed() is invoked in an ActionListener by the Swing Event Thread. So there should only be one thread ever calling the method.

Comment: Ok. Only one thread will ever call your method and it will call it every 200 milliseconds. Do you see this happening? Your method is synchronized on its object. Who else is synchronized on the object. Maybe you are dead locked. Does the call to actionPerformed complete correctly? Maybe if you describe the actual problem we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can lock on an `Object` (instead of `this`) which is shared across group of Threads where you need real synchronization

lock object

```
Object lockGroup1 = new Object();
```

Thread that holds it

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
  Object lock;
  public MyThread(Object lock){
     this.lock = lock;
  }
  // other stuff ofcourse
}
```

and

```
MyThread thread1 = new MyThread(lock1);
```

---

Updates based on Comments

```
    Set<Long> waitingThreads = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Long>());
    public void myMethod() {
     waitingThreads.add(Thread.currentThread().getId());
     synchronized (this){
        waitingThreads.remove(Thread.currentThread().getId());

      }
    }
```

Comment: HI Jigar, 
I want to handle / Identify those thread those failed to enter that block. Is that possible with my code snippet ?

Comment: it is certainly possible, may I know what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: simply want to print("Could not Enter The Block"); How can I do that.?

Comment: if it is just for this particular code block (not widely spreaded in the system) I would maintain a synchronized `Set<Long>` updating answer

Comment: That is away from what I want.